# Why plot function in likert producing error?

Tags: r, likert

My data is:

```
>   dput(fb5)
structure(list(Relevency = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Clarity = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Technical01 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Technical02 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Technical03 = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Technical04 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Technical05 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Interactive = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Response = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Length = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Progress = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Expectation = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Performance = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Relevency", 
"Clarity", "Technical01", "Technical02", "Technical03", "Technical04", 
"Technical05", "Interactive", "Response", "Length", "Progress", 
"Expectation", "Performance", "Class"), row.names = c("id 1", 
"id 2", "id 3", "id 4", "id 5", "id 6", "id 7", "id 8", "id 9", 
"id 10", "id 11", "id 12", "id 13", "id 14", "id 15", "id 16", 
"id 17", "id 18", "id 19", "id 20", "id 21", "id 22", "id 23", 
"id 24", "id 25", "id 26", "id 27", "id 28", "id 29", "id 30", 
"id 31", "id 32", "id 33"), class = "data.frame")
```

When I request likert plot by:

```
likertG.fb5 <- likert(subset(fb5, select = -c(Class)), nlevels = 5)
plot(likertG.fb5)
```

I get result. But when I request likert plot by group using:

```
likertG.fb5 <- likert(subset(fb5, select = -c(Class)), nlevels = 5, grouping = fb5$Class)
plot(likertG.fb5)
```

I get the error message,

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "low", value = c(0, 0, 66.6666666666667,  : 
>     replacement has 12 rows, data has 13

Comment: I guess it is the likert package? Maybe, add e.g. `require(likert)` to your code

Comment: I don't know the likert package and therefore not familiar with the function, but it might be a problem with your grouping using `fb5$Class` instead of quoted or unquoted `grouping = Class`

Comment: I think you should contact the maintainer of the package, there seams to be few similar issues logged already: https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues/50